# Updating a subdocument with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple polls app with angular, express, and mongoose.

My data looks like this:`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var responseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    responseText: String,
    votes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Responses', responseSchema);

var pollsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    responses: [responseSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Polls', pollsSchema);`
```

So, I have a polls model which holds a subdocument responses model.

When someone votes, I want to increase the vote count of the response.
Here is the query that I'm working on but it's not right.

```
router.post('/api/polls/:id/vote', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("Poll ID : " + req.params.id);
    console.log("Option ID : " + req.body._id);
    Polls.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, {

        $inc: {
            'responses.id(req.body.id).votes': 1
        }

    }, function (err, post) {

        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(post);
        console.log(post.responses.id(req.body._id).votes);
    });
})
```

Edit: Updated

Basically, I'm sending the Poll ID in the req params and the response id in the response body. I'm able to console.log the vote value, but I don't know how to write the query. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: Basically just use findOne to narrow down the id, then perform the query in the callback. Seems a little weird, but it works. If anyone else has a better way, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

```
router.post('/api/polls/:id/vote', function (req, res, next) {

    Polls.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, 'responses', function (err, post) {
        post.responses.id(req.body._id).votes++;
        post.save();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `$inc` operator. See [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

```
Polls.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.params.id,
        responses._id: req.body._id
    }, {
        {$inc: {'responses.$.votes': 1}}
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, It doesn't seem to be incrementing unfortunately. Is there any way to debug what's not working?

That does look like exactly what I want to do though.

Comment: err is null, post seems to return the entire object (id, question, responses[]).

I'll update the original post with the updated code.

Comment: Found a solution using findOne, thanks for the help. I posted it below.